# Simulating t-test p-values using a for loop

Tags: r, loops, statistics

For this project I am required to use an R script to simulate the effectiveness of the t-test. I must use a for loop will be used to carry out the following 2000 times:

Would the loop look something like this

```
i <- 1
for (i <= 2001) { 
    x <-rf(5,df1=5,df2=10)
    b <- df2
    p.value <-t.test(x,mu=(b/(b-2))$p.value
    i <- i+1
}
```

Comment: This is an obvious homework question.

Comment: @Colin Yeah, but it isn't a bad one, as far as they go. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Well, even if it's homework at least he tried to do it and included a piece of code... +1 for trying

Comment: @nico If you look closer you could see that he don't look on help page to `for` (semantic is wrong) and he don't execute this code. So -1 for pretending to do something. He use StackOverflow as R code interpreter. Someone should answer `Error: unexpected '<=' in "for (i <="`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the way you wrote it, it would be a "while" loop.

For loops in R have the following syntax:

```
for (i in 1:2000) {
    df1 <- 5
    df2 <- 10
    x <-rf(5, df1=df1, df2=df2)
    b <- df2
    p.value <- t.test(x, mu=(b/(b-2)))$p.value
}
```

Additionally, it might be more efficient to employ an "apply" construct, for example with replicate, and include the df as function arguments:

```
get.p.value <- function(df1, df2) {
        x <- rf(5, df1=df1, df2=df2)
        p.value <- t.test(x, mu=(df2/(df2-2)))$p.value
    }
replicate (2000, get.p.value(df1 = 5, df2 = 10))
```

This is not always true, but it simplifies the recovery of the p.values.

Comment: In your first solution you could take assignments out of loop. There id no need to 2000 times assign the same value. So it could be done like `df1<-5;df2<-b<-10;for(i in 1:2000) p.value <- t.test(rf(5, df1=df1, df2=df2), mu=(b/(b-2)))$p.value`

Comment: And for `for` version (in my modification too) results aren't save. So after loop you stay with one value. So your replicate solution is much better. +1 for this

Comment: You're right Marek, the assignments to df1, df2, b (why b in the first place?) should be out of the loop. Even mu could be pre-computed.
To save the p.values, the worst is to grow a vector with `p.values <- c(p.values, t.test(...))` in the `for` loop. `replicate` somehow pre-allocates a vector of the desired length at the beginning, and avoid slow memory re-allocations.
For long computations, think about the `plyr` package that can display progression bars.

Comment: ok im slightly confused by that calimo (also thanks again for the help) 
i chose b as i assignmed <-df2 to it and then in the t.test i used the B value rather than df2 so that way i could easily change the input value of df2.

this is the actual link to what im doing its rather short if you wanted to look. 

http://www.2shared.com/document/lf3biLds/R_assignment_two.html

Comment: @Simon To change the input of df2, include it as function argument. I edited my answer to include that.