# How to create a for loop in R?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [how to start a for loop in R programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162363/how-to-start-a-for-loop-in-r-programming)
>   [Creating a for loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864920/creating-a-for-loop-in-r)

HI
Here's the scenario

Speed dating: You are confident that you have a 15% chance of landing a date with any given 
candidate at a local speed dating event. At the event, you will meet exactly 8 candidates. After you talk to a candidate for 5 minutes, he/she will immediately indicate if she wants to go on a date with you.

The question is...

Through simulation, find your chances that the third candidate you meet is the first to 
offer you a date.

I am looking for the R code (I think it's a for loop) that will answer this question

Comment: Homework? Regardless, see this Q for advice on using loops in R: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162363/how-to-start-a-for-loop-in-r-programming

Comment: @Joe (fake name) Is this a homework question?

Comment: @Joe Do you want to know how to do a `for` loop in R, or do you want the answer to this question about dating?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864920/creating-a-for-loop-in-r

Comment: Shane- I am looking for the answer to this question

Comment: @Joe Want to take a stab at it yourself?  Maybe post the pseudo code?  As it stands, it looks like you're trying to farm your homework out to us...

Comment: @Joe *which* question - the one in the title (how to create a loop in R?) or your homework (chances of getting a date)?

Comment: Gavin- haha, i am looking for an answer to the one in the title.

Comment: oops, meant to keep going. So maybe

Comment: @Joe Can you somehow convince us this isn't Homework? If you can I've got an answer waiting to post - but I work at a University and I wouldn't want my students doing what you are doing if you are a student. If this is homework, the purpose is to learn not to get the answer.

Comment: OK, a serious answer coming up...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't a loop, but it is a bit more R-centric:

```
N <- 1000 ## number of simulations to run
## Make this reproducible by seeding the random number generator
set.seed(1)
## read ?sample to see how this works
## Basically, sampling accept/not accept with 0.15/0.85 probability,
## N (1000) times for each of three Girls
df <- data.frame(Girl1 = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), N, replace = TRUE,
                 prob = c(0.15,0.85)),
                 Girl2 = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), N, replace = TRUE,
                 prob = c(0.15,0.85)),
                 Girl3 = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), N, replace = TRUE,
                 prob = c(0.15,0.85)))
## Show some of the data
head(df)
## the row sums tell us how many accepts you'd get, 1, 2, or 3
outcomes <- rowSums(df)
## We want the rows with 1 acceptance **and** where Girl3 == TRUE
wanted <- with(df, which(outcomes == 1L & Girl3))
## This gives us the simulation probability
length(wanted) / N
```

Sorry it isn't a loop - but you can try to do it in a loop using the above for guidance. Can't have us doing all the work.

Comment: in your code, does <-  mean the same thing as an equal sign?

Comment: @Joe In R, `=` and `<-` are equivalent assignment operators, but `<-` is preferred stylistically.

Comment: @Joe - just to add to Shane's comment, in general `=` and `<-` can be used interchangeably,  but there are situations where you can't use `=` where you can use `<-`. An example is `with(df, new <- Girl1)`, when `with(df, new = Girl1)` fails.

Comment: Can I ask another question...in this line of code... " wanted <- with(df, which(outcomes == 1L & Girl3))"...where does the L come from? Can I use "P" or "Q" or any other letter. So, why do I use L in particular

Comment: Yes, Joe, you can ask. Whether anyone answers will depend on several things like whether you **accept** one of the answer provided to your questions as it helps people get rep and take a more active part in the site. When we get enough rep we can edit Qs, change tags etc, to make the whole StackOverflow thing that much better a resource.

Comment: As to your Q, no, you can't just put any old letter in there. `1` in R is a numeric (i.e. a floating point double). If you want an *integer*, you append the `L` to it. So `1L` is just the safe way of specifying the integer `1`.

Comment: ok, I accepted your answer. Sorry, I'm new to the site, and didn't know I should do that (or even how to do that). So, lemme see if I understand... The L says I want an integer, and the 1 specifies which integer I want (in this case 1 success). With the L, does R already know what this means? Because when I type in "?L", R doesn't have an explanation. Yet, in the code, I didn't have to specify what L means. How does that work?

Comment: @Joe; the `L` is part of the syntax. It is part of R's internals, but I forget now where it is documented.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a for loop example:

```
for (i in 1:1e7) {
  cat("I LOVE HOMEWORK!!  ")
}
```

Comment: @Dirk It's bad behavior to edit someone else's thoughtful answer.

Comment: that's why I used cat instead of paste(); I like the scroll effect. It reminds me of my first Basic programs!

Comment: JD- could you re post your answer since Dirk messed with it

Comment: @Joe - he didn't mess with it in any substantive way. And anyway, click on the words next to "edited" above Dirk's head and you'll see the revision history of JD's Answer

Comment: So this freezes the R program cause 1e7 is really big. Its funny that I didn't realize that til after I crashed R. Well played sir